# execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject External entry point

Tags: trigger, soql, list

I have created a trigger to update the **Priority** of a custom object (**JIRA_Issue__c**) when the **Priority** of the related **Case** is updated.

So Basically when a **JIRA_Issue__c** is created for a related **Case**, the **priority** of the **JIRA_Issue__c** = the **Priority** of the Case.

If later, I decide to update the Case Priority to **Medium** for example, then the JIRA_Issue__c **Priority** is also updated to **Medium**

But I have an error on my trigger in line 11:

```
CaseManager.updateJiraIssuePriority(caseList);
```

**CaseTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject External entry point Trigger.CaseTrigger: line 11**

here is my code:

```
public class CaseManager {

public static void updateJiraIssuePriority(List<Case> caseList) {
    List<JIRA_Issue__c> jiraList = new List<JIRA_Issue__c>();
    for(Case c : [SELECT Id, Priority, (SELECT Id, Priority__c FROM JIRA_Issues__r) FROM Case]) {
        jiraList.add(c.JIRA_Issues__r);
        System.debug('##### jiraList ' + jiraList);
        for(JIRA_Issue__c ji : jiraList) {
            ji.Priority__c = c.Priority;
        }
    }
    if(jiraList.size() > 0) {
        update jiraList;
    }
    
}

}
```

here is my trigger

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (after insert, after update) {

List<Case> caseList = new List<Case>();
if(Trigger.isAfter) {
    for(Case c : Trigger.New) {
        if(Trigger.newMap.get(c.Id).Priority != Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Priority) {
            caseList.add(c);  
        }
    }
    if(caseList.size() > 0) {
        CaseManager.updateJiraIssuePriority(caseList);
    }
}
}
```

I tried to fix the error by editing my method in the following manner:

```
public static void updateJiraIssuePriority(List<Case> caseList) {
    List<JIRA_Issue__c> jiraList = new List<JIRA_Issue__c>();
    JIRA_Issue__c jIssue = null;
    for(Case c : [SELECT Id, Priority, (SELECT Id, Priority__c FROM JIRA_Issues__r) FROM Case]) {
        jiraList.add(c.JIRA_Issues__r);
        System.debug('##### jiraList ' + jiraList);
        for(JIRA_Issue__c ji : jiraList) {
            ji.Priority__c = c.Priority;
        }
    }
    if(!jiraList.isEmpty()) {
        jIssue = jiraList[0];
    }
    
}
```

But I still have the same erro!
Could someone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would surmise your issue is in this line:

```
for(Case c : [SELECT Id, Priority, (SELECT Id, Priority__c FROM JIRA_Issues__r) FROM Case]) { ...
```

Your query is non-selective, you are returning all cases

You most likely meant:

```
for(Case c : [SELECT Id, Priority, (SELECT Id, Priority__c FROM JIRA_Issues__r) 
                 FROM Case
                 WHERE ID IN: caseList]) { ...
```